# Laser line detection opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to detect a laser line for an autonomous system.

My work till now:
1. I split the image in rgb channels
2. use only the red channel because             of using a red laser line
3. get threshold value manually 
4.searching the binary image for a value != 0

I can't threshold it manually for the use case of an automous system any ideas how to  solve the problem ?

And only searching of the highest peak in an image isn't good enough because  of incidence of sunlight.

Maybe I can search for short peaks..
Because in the region of the laser line the brightness increase fast and then decrease fast after the laser line.

How can I realize that in opencv?

[image: Image with laser]

[image: manual treshholded image]

[image: with an object]

Comment: You can maybe try [Laplacian](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/laplace_operator/laplace_operator.html).

Comment: In a longshot - this will just not work. You have to use filter for your camera that will pass olny your laser wavelength. If not you will not be able to segment your laser line from all the noise data you will get using just R threshold.

Comment: Can I use the other 2 channels to get a better solution ?

Comment: maybe use HSV hue channel instead of RGB R channel

Comment: I tried that already but the results are also bad :(

Comment: [Line detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)?

Comment: How about posting one, or more, images?

Comment: I can't I need at least 10 reputation to post images

Comment: I like your question... you may find you have enough now...

Comment: How can I get 10 reputation, I would post a picture

Comment: Is there always just one line? Or sometimes multiple lines? Are the lines always near vertical? Or near horizontal? Do the lines generally stretch the full length/width or the frame or nearly so?

Comment: For the beginning I want to use one line. Yes the lines should be vertical...,and they stretch the full length

Comment: The preferred approach is to use a lens color filter based on the laser wavelength, and you need a laser bright enough to dominate the ambient light.  It helps if you have a high quality laser that uses a powell lens for even intensity over its width.  If it's a red laser and you've got a color camera, you may have some luck using the red channel and subtracting a weighted portion green channel (such as green_channel*0.50).  If you have the option, use 2 images, one with the laser and one without, then use background segmentation to extract the laserline as a change from the previous image.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Ok, I have had a look at your updated picture. My algorithm comes down to the following steps.

- Find Brightest Column (i.e. laser line) in Image
- Find Dark Gap in Brightest Column
- Find Neighbouring Column That is Brightest in Gap in laser line

**Step 1 - Find Brightest Column (i.e. laser line) in Image**

The easiest way to do this is to squidge the image down so it is still its original width, but just one pixel high effectively averaging the pixels in each vertical column of the image. Then apply an `-auto-level` to contrast stretch that to the full range of 0-255 and threshold it at 95% to find all columns that are within 5% of the brightest. Then look for pixels that have thresholded out to white (#ffffff). This is one line in ImageMagick, as follows:

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P1zj.jpg -colorspace gray \
    -resize x1!                                             \
    -auto-level                                             \
    -threshold 95% text: | grep -i ffffff
```

**Output:**

```
297,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
298,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
299,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white
```

So, I now know that columns 297-299 are the the ones where the laser line is. Note that if the picture is slightly rotated, or the laser is not vertical, the bright column will be split across multiple columns. To counteract this, you could shrink the width of the image by a factor of two or three so that adjacent columns tend to get merged into one in the smaller image, then just multiply up the column by the shrink factor to find the original position.

That completes Step 1, but an alternative method follows before Step 2.

I split the image into columns 1 pixel wide with:

```
convert input.png -crop 1x +repage line%d.png
```

Now I find the brightest column (one with highest mean brightness) with:

```
for f in line*; do m=$(convert -format "%[fx:mean]" $f info:);echo $m:$f ;done | sort -g
```

which gives this

```
...
...
0.559298:line180.png
0.561051:line185.png
0.561337:line306.png
0.562527:line184.png
0.562939:line183.png
0.584523:line295.png
0.590632:line299.png
0.644543:line296.png
0.671116:line298.png
0.71122:line297.png      <--- brightest column = 297
```

**Step 2 - Find Dark Gap in Brightest Column**

Now I take column 297 and auto-level it so the darkest part becomes zero and the lightest part becomes white, then I negate it.

```
convert line297.png -colorspace gray -auto-level -threshold 20% -negate txt:

...
0,100: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,101: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,102: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,103: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,104: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,105: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,106: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,107: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,108: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white  <- gap in laser line
0,109: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white  <- gap in laser line
0,110: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white  <- gap in laser line
0,111: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white  <- gap in laser line
0,112: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,113: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
...
0,478: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,479: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
```

**Step 3 - Find Neighbouring Column That is Brightest in Gap in laser line**

Now if I multiply this column with each of the columns either side of it, all parts of the other columns that are not in the gap in the laser line will become zero and all parts that are in the gap in the laser line will be multiplied and totalled up as I run through the columns either side of column 297.

So, I check columns 240 to 340, multiplying each column with the mask from the previous step and seeing which one is brightest in the gap in the laser line:

```
for i in {240..340} ;do n=$(convert line${i}.png mask.png -compose multiply -composite -format "%[mean]" info:);echo $n:$i ;done | sort -g
```

The output is as follows:

```
458.495:248
466.169:249
468.668:247
498.294:260
502.756:250
536.844:259
557.726:258
564.508:251
624.117:252
627.508:253  <--- column 253 is brightest
```

Then I can see that column 253 is the  brightest in the area where the laser line is darkest. So the displaced line is in column 253.

I am sure this technique could be done fairly easily in `opencv`.

**Original Answer**

I can tell you a way to do it, but not give you any code for `opencv` as I tend to use ImageMagick. I split the image into a series of vertical images, each 1 pixel wide - i.e. single pixel columns. Then I get the average of the brightnesses in all columns and can immediately see the brightest column. It works pretty well, here is how I tested the algorithm:

```
Split image into single pixel columns
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMiU1.jpg -crop 1x +repage line%04d.png
```

See what we got:

```
ls line*
line0000.png    line0128.png    line0256.png    line0384.png    line0512.png
line0001.png    line0129.png    line0257.png    line0385.png    line0513.png
...
line0126.png    line0254.png    line0382.png    line0510.png    line0638.png
line0127.png    line0255.png    line0383.png    line0511.png    line0639.png
```

Yes, 640 vertical lines. Check size of one...

```
identify line0639.png 
line0639.png PNG 1x480 1x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.33KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Yes, it's 1 pixel wide and 480 pixels high.

Now get mean brightness of all lines and sort by brightness:

```
for f in line*; do m=$(convert -format "%[fx:mean]" $f info:);echo $m:$f ;done | sort -g
```

**Output**

```
0.5151:line0103.png
0.521621:line0104.png
0.527829:line0360.png
0.54699:line0356.png
0.567822:line0355.png
0.752827:line0358.png  <--- highest brightness
0.76616:line0357.png   <--- highest brightness
```

Columns 357 and 358 seem to be readily identifiable as your answer.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I posted one more picture. There is an Object in the image and the pos. of the laser line is changing. I need also the position of both lines to get a distance with triangulation.